# maas-pserv main process ended, respawning

Tags: server, python, apache2, maas

I was trying to get MAAS cluster controller running on Ubuntu 14.04 using a clean server install and adding the MAAS package for the cluster-controller manually later.
I have another machine running the maas-regional-controller.

I have two issues with the controller installation:

1. Apache 2 hangs when installing the maas-cluster-controller package, due to some missing python module called `crochet`
2. `maas-pserv` crashes with error code 1, gets re-spawned and finally is stopped by init, due to the high frequency of the restarts.

I installed the `python-crochet` package, in order to make apache start. Is this something due to some omission in the dependency list of apache installation?
Hopefully it was ok to install the package in the first place.

The `maas-pserv` does not start and I don't know due to which cause. I tried to look into the log files in `/var/log/maas`, but pserv does not write any log file, maybe since the crash is created by upstart. I tried to start pserv manually through the twistd call as in `/etc/init/maas-pserv.conf`. twisted complains that it does not know the command `maas-pserv`.

By no means I'm a python expert, but I only can imagine (educated guess) that twisted is not importing the maas python application library and therefore complains about not knowing about it.

An ideas why `maas-pserv` is crashing?

Answer (score 0):

For the `maas-pserv` problem i've maybe a solution. I had the issue today also on one of my MAAS controllers and i found out that `twistd` has a cache file that contains all plugin information.

I simply deleted the `dropin.cache` file and `twistd` will find the `maas-pserv` now.

`dropin.cache` is located on `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/plugins` at my machines.